# Pip install error for glpk in Mavericks?

Tags: python, pip, glpk

I get the following error when trying "pip install glpk" but I get a series of errors. This is not like post 22135568, which actually was resolved with the command I'm using.

The errors look like:

```
In file included from src/lp.c:24:

src/kkt.h:30:3: error: unknown type name 'LPXKKT'

LPXKKT kkt;

^

src/lp.c:182:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_read_model' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    self->lp = lpx_read_model(model[0], model[1], model[2]);

             ^

src/lp.c:182:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'glp_prob *' (aka 'struct glp_prob *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

    self->lp = lpx_read_model(model[0], model[1], model[2]);

           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/lp.c:338:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_read_bas' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

if (lpx_read_bas(LP, bas_filename)) {

    ^

src/lp.c:349:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_OK'

case LPX_E_OK:        Py_RETURN_NONE;

     ^
```

I have tried homebrew but this does not install glpk. For context, I'm using the iPython notebook.

Comment: have you tried an older version of gplk?

Comment: have a look here http://blog.ducky.io/python/2013/07/01/Installing-Python-glpk/.

Comment: With homebrew, even when I install package x, I cannot import package x. I'd have to change the directory homebrew installs to (which is another issue I'm not sure how to handle). Ideally, I'd like to switch from homebrew installing to Cellar to install to /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages, as pip does.

Comment: did you install the python bindings also?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to "import glpk" but it's not connected to cvxopt.